# значение s и почему оно такое ? что конкретно происходит здесь s += A[i]>0;

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int s = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        s += A[i]>0;
    }
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: конкретно там у вас справа то присваивания логическое выражение, которое пинимает значение истина или ложь. Поскольку речь идет о числовом сложении, то результат этого логического выражение приводится к целому и принимает значение 1 или 0. на выходе имеем что s увеличивается на 1 если a[i] положительные. Почему начальное s = 1 - вопрос к автору кода, т.к. вероятно смысл алгоритма был в подсчете числа положительных элементов массива.

Comment: по моему, предыдущий комментарий полностью отвечает на вопрос

Comment: @teran, оформите как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В си-подобных языках конструкция `x += y` это сокращенная запись `x = x + y`.
справа то знака (оператора) присваивания у вас логическое выражение `a[i] > 0`. Логическое выражение при вычислении принимает значение  `true` или `false`, а при сложении неявно приводится к целому типу и становится `1` или `0`.
Таким образом, когда элемент массива положительный, то получаем `s += 1`, а если 0 или меньше, то `s += 0`. В итоге данный цикл считает число положительных элементов массива.
Возникает вопрос, почему начальное значение `s = 1`, но тут вам подскажет только тот, кто этот код написал.